How do I add subtitles to this?
Im creating a python video thing where it uses moviepy and a tts file as the audio along with some music:
# Paths
background_video_path = "src/bgvid.mp4"
output_audio_path = "output/output-tts.mp3"
output_video_path = "output/output-nosubtitles.mp4"

# Read JSON data from config.json
with open("config.json", "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Load audio
song_clip = AudioFileClip(data["song"]).volumex(0.09)  # Reduce volume to 20%
tts_clip = AudioFileClip(output_audio_path)

# Ensure song duration matches TTS audio duration
min_duration = min(song_clip.duration, tts_clip.duration)
song_clip = song_clip.subclip(0, min_duration)
tts_clip = tts_clip.subclip(0, min_duration)

# Combine song and TTS audio
combined_audio = CompositeAudioClip([song_clip.set_duration(min_duration), tts_clip.set_duration(min_duration)])

# Crop background video
cropped_video = crop_video(background_video_path)

# Shorten video to match audio length
cropped_video = cropped_video.subclip(0, min_duration)

# Set combined audio to cropped video
final_video = cropped_video.set_audio(combined_audio)

# Write final video
final_video.write_videofile(output_video_path, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac', fps=24)



thats the code and it uses a output-tts.mp3 file as audio which is a person talking and some gameplay clip. there is also some code im not sharing for changing aspect ratio from cropping to 9:16 and yeah.
I want to add subtitles to this so like it displays subtitles in the center.
I already tried using ImageMagick but it came with a blank background some text in the center that wont change and goes out of 9:16 aspect ratio and a 10 minute long video with nothing else.
So I came here asking if anyone could help in helping me add subtitle code so that it could display subtitles in the center

if you get image with background then maybe first convert text to images PNG without background ie using pillow or Wand (which uses ImageMagick) and later put these images as clips.

did you try to use TextClip

WAIT! IT ACTUALLY WORKS NOW... I SPENT LIKE HOURS!

I used pillow to convert each caption into an image and then put it into the correct time frame for each and the captions are working now... thanks for the suggestion :)

Edit:
I used pillow to convert each subtitle into a image and put it into a folder for captions saving each of them... then displayed it onto the video and exported the video w captions
